# How do I replace the paw of this mesh?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to character modeling and went about modeling the paws on this model all wrong. After following a tutorial to create new paws, I can't figure out how to attach said paws to the original model without individually filling each polygon in between. I realize I went about the whole process all wrong and might have to start from square one, but is there any way to fix it? [image]

Comment: you should work with less topology, it would make all correction much easier, then at the end you can add topology if it's really necessary, to add some details.

Answer (score 2):

A few ways, try:

- Using Bridge Loops to automatically connect two loops of edges so you don't need to individually fill each polygon. (Select edge loops > Context Menu/Edge > Bridge Edge Loops). Use the settings menu that pops up to configure the shape. (You can only bridge edge loops on the same mesh. You would need to remove the old paws and position the new ones, then ctrl+j to join the objects to main mesh)

[image]

- Use Boolean modifiers. Remove old paw and fill end, making sure you don't leave any holes in the mesh. Position new paws so they intersect with the legs. Then add a Boolean modifier to the main body/mesh set to "Union" and select the paw as the "Object". Press ctrl+a on the boolean modifier to apply and make one mesh.

[image]

Comment: Bridge loops worked perfectly, thank you so much!!